# How to convert UTC string to date by ignoring timezone?

Tags: swift, date, timezone, nsdateformatter

I have UTC like this `2017-03-26T11:53:31+05:00`. I should get `date` or `string` from it ignoring timezone. In other words, from above string I should get `2017-03-26 11:53:31` no matter in which format. Here is my try:

```
fileprivate let formatter: DateFormatter = {
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)
   return dateFormatter
}()

print(formatter.date(from: "2017-03-26T11:53:31+06:00"))
```

But above code prints this: `2017-03-26 05:53:31 +0000`. Why is that and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `Date` is okay, but `print` is printing it in your local timezone (generally done for your conveience). If you want to print it out in UTC, you'll have to format it into a string using a `DateFormatter`, wit hthe date set to UTC.

Comment: Hmm, you mean is `print` is guilty for this. I don't know to print it to UTC, I just want to convert UTC string to my own format of date string.Of course, completely ignoring timezone.

Comment: "I have UTC like this 2017-03-26T11:53:31+05:00" ??? This is not UTC time "+05:00" is the timezone of your date string. The `Z` at the end of your dateFormat string is used to parse your string.. If you use your date formatter to create a string from your parsed date it will create a UTC string representation because you are setting the timezone to zero seconds from GMT

Comment: If it is not UTC, then what is it? GMT?

Comment: if is +6 hours as it states "2017-03-26T11:53:31+06:00" so UTC is 6 hours behind +0000

Comment: UTC and GMT 0 is the same

Comment: Btw make sure to set your date formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat otherwise it might fail is the user's device 24hour settings is set to 12 hours (am / pm). Or make your life easier and use the ISO8601DateFormatter which would work in this case with its default settings

Comment: Thanks, but iso works from iOS 10 only. 
About my problem. Why it does not work? I get that date string from server and need to convert it ignoring timezone it sends.